# AntiDetect Browser with CefSharp

Tags: c#

How to change finger print of session? I use CefSharp in my WPF web browser project. I want to make each tab of session with dynamic fingerPrint, How can i change UserAgent,WebGL, GeoLocation and etc. to change FingerPrint?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single fingerprint. There are a lot of fingerprinting techniques, which allow even detecting different browsers on the same machine.

If you want to change e.g. the user agent, check out [`CefSettings.UserAgent`](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_CefSettings_UserAgent.htm) property.

Comment: I want to change, more fingerprint techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can implement proxy and change screen sizes. But you they can still detect a CefSharp browser using "typeof CefSharp" via JavaScript. I don't see any way we can prevent it.